# mysql select within select

Tags: php, mysql

this is the first time I'm dabbling in Databases and was wondering if it was possible to do the following:
I have two tables

```
student (id, name, phone)
photos  (id, student_id, photo)
```

I wanted to retrieve the student phone who's name is say 'Tom' but only if he has a photo. 
Is it possible at all to have a condition like this?

Many thanks

Comment: You need to read up on joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select s.phone from student s 
inner join photos p 
on p.student_id=s.id
where p.photo is not null
```

Comment: @bryanmac: Assuming that `photos.photo` is nullable.

Comment: @ypercube: Can't that be inferred from the question? `only if it has a photo...`

Comment: @Icarus: It's `from student`, not `students`. You also need the `where name = 'Tom'`.

Comment: Infered? No. I would assume that a user has a photo if there is a row in table `photos` with his `id`. But adding `where p.photo is not null` doesn't hurt in either case.

Answer (score 0):

That is called an `INNER JOIN`.

```
select top 1 name from student s 
inner join photos p
on s.id = p.student_id
where name like 'Tom'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT phone
FROM student
WHERE name = 'Tom'
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM photos
        WHERE photos.student_id = student.id
      )
```

or using `JOIN`. You need to use either `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` so you don't get the same phone 20 times if the user has 20 photos:

```
SELECT DISTINCT student.phone
FROM student
  JOIN photos
    ON photos.student_id = student.id
WHERE student.name = 'Tom'
```

Comment: Should be an inner join imo, which does away with the need for a DISTINCT, let the app select which photo to display. Also I think you meant 'same photo 20'.

Comment: No, I meant same phone. We have `SELECT phone`, not `SELECT photo`.

Comment: Also: `INNER JOIN` is the same as `JOIN`. Neither gets away with the need for `DISTINCT`, if we want to display only phone and not phone+photos.

Comment: Ahhh my bad. For some reason I thought `JOIN` was a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use a join. Try this:

```sql
SELECT student.phone
FROM students
INNER JOIN photos
ON student.id=photos.student_id
WHERE student.name LIKE 'Tom'
```